# Representing a transformation in 2 dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have watched [this video about linear transformations and matrices](https://youtu.be/kYB8IZa5AuE) and I would like to represent a matrix the same way in my thesis. Here it is:

[image: Matrix]

As you can see, the x and y axis are represented in white while the transformed domain is in blue. The background shows the standard domain.

I am used to use tikzpicture to represent simple shapes but I do not know how to create grids like the one in the image, how to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with the background grid: [this site](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/27/tikz-series-pt1.html) creates a simple grid like this:

```
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-2,-2) grid (6,6);
```

Your background grid has minor and major step sizes, so we draw two grids:

```
\draw[step=0.5cm, gray!20!white, very thin] (-7, -3) grid (7, 3);
\draw[step=1cm, gray!60!white, thin] (-7, -3) grid (7, 3);
```

[image]

The next step is the grid for the new basis, the blue parallelograms. You can use a `\foreach` loop to make translated copies of a given line, like this:

```
\foreach \x in {-4,...,4} {
    \draw[color=blue, thick] (-1 + 1.5*\x, -3) -- (1 + 1.5*\x, 3);
}
```

The second basis direction is very similar.

[image]

The new axes should be a different color, but we can just draw them over the blue ones by making them just slightly thicker:

```
\draw[color=green!80!black, line width=1.05pt] (-1, -3) -- (1, 3);
\draw[color=green!80!black, line width=1.05pt] (-7, -1) -- (7, 1);

\draw[color=red!80!black, line width=1.10pt, ->] (0, 0) -- (1/3, 1);
\draw[color=red!80!black, line width=1.10pt, ->] (0, 0) -- (2, 2/7);
```

The grid is complete; all you have to do is add the matrices.

[image]

Here's the complete code. If you want to adjust the diagram, or use different basis vectors, it would be better to define shortcuts governing the slopes of the lines rather than hardcoding everything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[step=0.5cm, gray!20!white, very thin] (-7, -3) grid (7, 3);
\draw[step=1cm, gray!60!white, thin] (-7, -3) grid (7, 3);

\foreach \x in {-4,...,4} {
    \draw[color=blue, thick] (-1 + 1.5*\x, -3) -- (1 + 1.5*\x, 3);
}
\foreach \y in {-2,...,2} {
    \draw[color=blue, thick] (-7, -1 + \y) -- (7, 1 + \y);
}

\draw[color=green!80!black, line width=1.05pt] (-1, -3) -- (1, 3);
\draw[color=green!80!black, line width=1.05pt] (-7, -1) -- (7, 1);

\draw[color=red!80!black, line width=1.10pt, ->] (0, 0) -- (1/3, 1);
\draw[color=red!80!black, line width=1.10pt, ->] (0, 0) -- (2, 2/7);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can actually see realtime the effect of the transformation on the basic grid. PDF specification allows one to write an affine transformation. If you scope the transformation it will be local to that scope.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (-2,-2) rectangle (6,6);
\draw[very thin,draw=gray!70] (-2,-2) grid[step=5mm] (6,6);
\draw[thick,draw=gray!50] (-2,-2) grid[step=1cm] (6,6);

\begin{scope}[]
  \clip (-2,-2) rectangle (6,6);
  \begin{scope}[cm={1,2,3,1,(0,0)}]
    \draw[draw=blue!50] (-2,-2) grid[step=1cm] (6,6);
  \end{scope}
\end{scope}

\draw[ultra thick,draw=red,latex-latex] (1,2) -- (0,0) -- (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]